# W3 Responsive Navbar Won't Work for My Application

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

For some reason the starter code from W3 for setting up a responsive nav bar is not working for my website.  I am trying to follow https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp . My navbar is structured a bit different than theirs.  Mine has nav tags, ul and li tags.  I'm thinking it has something to do with how I'm navigating the DOM but I'm just not able to get it.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've already tried changing the media queries to be .topnav ul li a instead of just .topnav a but that doesn't work either.

```
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img id="logo" src="your-choice-logo.jpg">
            </div>
            <nav class="topnav" id="myTopNav">    
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#welcome-section">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#scheduling">Make Appointment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</li></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#areas-served">Areas Served</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#facebook">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, 
except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains 
should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav ul li a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript 
when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look 
good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of 
horizontally) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive ul li a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }

  /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small 
screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to 
topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here.

- You have problems with html tags (some of them closing before the nested tag is closed).
- For some styles you should use `li` (display/position/float), while for some `a` (visual styling), as `li` are placed beside of each other, while `a` inside of the `li` and technically can't be `:not(:first-child)` for example.
- Using `ul` for such lists you should reset its styling with `style-list: none; margin: 0; padding: 0`.
- You have a different id in JS and in HTML (attribute values in HTML and almost everything in JS are case-sensitive).

Check out the fixed version below.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to 
topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopNav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, 
except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains 
should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav ul li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav ul li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript 
when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look 
good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of 
horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small 
screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* BASIC STYLES */


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="your-choice-logo.jpg">
  </div>
  <nav class="topnav" id="myTopNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#welcome-section">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#scheduling">Make Appointment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="#areas-served">Areas Served</a></li>
      <li><a href="#facebook">Facebook</a></li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars">=</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

BTW, w3schools has nothing with W3 consortium. You should not consider w3schools as an authoritative resource. However it contains some simple and handy tutorials.